# Can I make an Angular structural directive in the form `myDirective('p')` that passes a value from the HMTL view to the directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm making an HTML view template with a button for each of the 28 vowels and the 59 consonants of the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). Each button will look like this:

```html
<button [ngStyle]="style_p()" (click)='phonemeClick("p")' mat-raised-button
        *ngIf="ipaView || language2.short==='en' || language2.short==='es' || language2.short==='zh' || language2.short==='fi' || language2.short==='ipa'"
        [matTooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition" [matTooltip]="tooltipMessage" [matTooltipDisabled]="tooltipDisabled">
        p {{exampleWords.p}}
        <span (click)='playAudio("p")'><mat-icon appHeadphonesIcon aria-hidden="false"
                aria-label="Headphones icon">headphones</mat-icon></span>
</button>
```

I can copy and paste that ugly block of HTML 87 times, each time typing another letter five times to replace the five occurrances of `p`. Can I make a structural directive that will look like

```html
<button myDirective('p')></button>
```

I see how to make a structural directive that changes an element in the DOM based on a value changing in the component, including values coming from the HTML view when the user clicks a button or submits a form. I don't see how to do this with values set in the HTML template.

I can't pass the `p` to the directive using `ngClick` because that would require waiting for the user to click the button. The directive needs to style the button before the user clicks the button.

I can't use `ngModel` because a button isn't a form.

How do I pass the `p` from the HTML view to the directive?

The five p's:

- set the style of the button (color, background, border-radius, etc.)
- when clicked, the button fires the `phonemeClick()` handler function and passes through the `p` as a parameter
- displays a `p` to the user
- displays `exampleWords.p` from the component
- when the user clicks the `headphones` icon (in the button) the `playMe()` handler function plays an audio file (passing through the `p` as a parameter

Comment: The format would be *myDirective=“p”. The asterix denotes a structural directive and basically turns the element into an ng-template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but why not just create a custom button component, pass it the letter as an input, and use your existing button template as it's template..

Comment: Additionally, instead of writing `language2.short==='en' || language2.short==='es' || language2.short==='zh' || language2.short==='fi' || language2.short==='ipa'"`, please just write instead: `['en', 'es', 'zh', 'fi', 'ipa'].includes(language2.short)`

Comment: And for extra points, move that logic out of the template and into a method, or better yet, a getter, in the component.

Answer (score 1):

The directives don't work in this way. To pass a value to a directive you use some like

```
<button myDirective='p'></button>

//and in your directive
@Input() myDirective:string=''
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek! Here's my custom button.

*phoneme-button.component.html*

```html
<button
    [type]="type"
    (click)="onClick()"
    [disabled]="isDisabled"
    class="btn"
    [ngStyle]="stylePhoneme"
    *ngIf="language2.short==='en' || language2.short==='zh' || language2.short==='fi' || language2.short==='ipa'"
    mat-raised-button>
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span>{{exampleWords}}</span>
    <span (click)='playAudio(text)'><mat-icon appHeadphonesIcon aria-hidden="false"
        aria-label="Headphones icon">headphones</mat-icon></span>
</button>
```

*consonant-chart.component.html*

```html
<app-phoneme-button text="b" 
  (btnClick)="btnClick($event)" 
  [homeToolbarObject]="homeToolbarObject" >
</app-phoneme-button>
```

*phoneme-button.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phoneme-button',
  templateUrl: './phoneme-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phoneme-button.component.css']
})
export class PhonemeButtonComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input()
    set text(name: string) {
        this.buttonText = name;
    switch (this.buttonText) {
      case 'b':
        this.exampleWords = "base";
        break;
        default:
          this.exampleWords = null;
    }
    }
    get name(): string | null {
        return this.buttonText;
    }

  stylePhoneme: any  =  {
    'color': 'white',
    'background': 'red',
    'border-radius': '0',
    'grid-column': '7/ span 3',
    'grid-row': '3/span 1',
  };

...
}
```

It works except for some CSS weirdness. The values for `color`, `background`, and `border-radius` pass through from `phoneme-button.component.ts` to `phoneme-button.component.html`, but the values for `grid-column` and `grid-row` don't pass from the component to the view.

Taking `[ngStyle]="stylePhoneme"` out of the custom button and putting the styling into the button:

*consonant-chart.component.html*

```html
<app-phoneme-button text="b" 
  style="grid-column: 1 / span 2; grid-row: 1 / span 1;"
  (btnClick)="btnClick($event)" 
  [homeToolbarObject]="homeToolbarObject" >
</app-phoneme-button>
```

puts the button in the right row, with the right `grid-column-start`, but `grid-column-end` is ignored. I'll ask another question.